# Insertion sort algorithm for use with remove method

Tags: c#, sorting, methods, insertion-sort, removeall

I am working on a project and I am wondering how I would setup the insertion sort method that will take the last character in an array list and move it to where the removeall method removed a character. My remove method is this:

```
public override void remove(ref T item)
    {
        if (next == 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {
            //find value, if it exists
            for (int i = 0; i < next; i++)
            {
                if (item.Equals(list[i]))
                {
                    for (int j = i; j < next; j++) list[j] = list[j + 1];
                    next--;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and my variables are:

```
u.print();
        int var = 5;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 12;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 2;
        u.insert(ref var);
        var = 29;
        u.insert(ref var);
        u.print();
        var = 5;
        u.remove(ref var);
        u.print();
```

I just don't know where I would put the insertion sort.

Comment: Can you try to explain more clearly what you want to do?

Comment: Yeah it is a little confusing, the remove method is supposed to remove a certain specified number from the list. But instead of having the list move every number up one, I need the insertion sort to take the number at the bottom of the list, and put it where the number that was removed was at.

Comment: Do you just want to replace your `for` loop with `list[i] = list[next];` ?

Comment: But the for loop is in the remove method, would I just copy the method and change it to an insertion sort?

Comment: Well, that is where the code that moves all the numbers up is, which is what you said you wanted to change.. I'm not sure how an insertion sort fits into this.

Comment: Perhaps you could give an example of a starting list, and then what you want to change it to..